# Steam and X11/Xorg: Steam overrides custom configuration?

Tags: ubuntu, x11, steam, xorg, xinput

I'm running Lubuntu 16.04, with xboxdrv version 0.8.6 (built from the [git repository](https://github.com/xboxdrv/ubuntu), as 0.8.5 is the version available in the Ubuntu repository), using an official Microsoft Xbox 360 wired controller, and running the official version of Steam for Linux.

There's an issue with xorg/x11 (I'm not sure what the more correct name is here, as I'm very new to Linux in general) where joysticks will by default have mouse control. From [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632026/how-can-i-stop-my-controller-from-moving-my-mouse) on the Ubuntu forums, this can be solved by creating `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-joystick.conf`:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "joystick catchall"
    MatchIsJoystick "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "joystick"
    Option "StartKeysEnabled" "False"   # These Two Lines Disable
    Option "StartMouseEnabled" "False"  # The mouse emulation
EndSection
```

This solves the issue, and will prevent the following from occurring:

When moving the left thumb stick, it also sends `EV_KEY` events (`KEY_LEFT` when moving it left, etc).

When moving the right thumb stick, different things occur, depending on the direction:

1. Moving the right stick up moves the mouse cursor to the LEFT,
2. Moving the right stick down moves the mouse cursor to the RIGHT,
3. Moving the right stick left seems to do nothing,
4. Moving the right stick right RIGHT CLICKS.

When pulling the left trigger, nothing odd seems to happen,

When pulling the right trigger, the mouse cursor MOVES DOWN; when released, the mouse cursor then MOVES UP, and will continue to until xboxdrv is stopped,

And finally, the directional pad seems to do nothing odd.

That is, until Steam for Linux is started. As soon as Steam is loaded and launched, everything above occurs as if `50-joystick.conf` had never been created. As soon as Steam is closed and xboxdrv is restarted, the gamepad works as expected.

When Steam is running, everything sends the correct event as well (triggers, sticks, etc), as they work in video games with the controller being detected as a gamepad. Additionally, these additional events don't seem to happen in game, only when the game loses focus.

As a side note, when running Steam through Wine (via PlayOnLinux), this does not occur. I don't know if the controller works in any games installed and launched through Wine Steam (I've set up koku's xinput libraries, following [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/RocketLeague/comments/3tknvf/how_to_get_your_controller_working_through_wine/) reddit thread; it works in GOG Spelunky), however.

Is there anything Steam does that modifies xorg/x11 that can either be prevented or reversed?

Comment: **UPDATE**: Well, I just found a partial solution to the controller issue, from [this](https://steamcommunity.com/app/107100/discussions/1/46476144867439551/) Steam Community post. Remapping LT to ABS_Z and RT to ABS_RZ instead of ABS_BRAKE and ABS_GAS respectively prevents the triggers from mucking things up. However, the right thumb stick still moves the mouse cursor (now with the cursor properly following the thumb stick's direction) and the left thumb stick sends arrow key signals, not sure what to do about that.

Comment: This is off-topic here because it isn't a programming question. There's a number of sites where it might be on topic: [su], [ubuntu.se], possibly [gaming.se]. I suspect [ubuntu.se] might have the best chance of getting good answers.